# Difference between SubstitutionSystem and StringReplace

Tags: string-manipulation, iteration, substitutionsystem

I'm examining two-step substitution model:

- First step, division: {"A" -> "BC", "B" -> "AC", "C" -> "AB"}
- Second step, merging: {"AA" -> "A", "BB" -> "B", "CC" -> "C"}

This code not work correctly:

```
rules =  {"A" -> "BC", "B" -> "AC", "C" -> "AB","AA" -> "A", "BB" -> "B", "CC" -> "C"};
SubstitutionSystem[rules, "A", 4]
```

Out = {"A", "BC", "ACAB", "BCA**BB**CAC", "ACA**BB**CBA**BB**CAB"}

Nor even this:

```
NestList[StringReplace[#, rules]&, "A", 4]
```

Out = {"A", "BC", "ACAB", "BCA**BB**CAC", "ACA**BB**CBA**BB**CAB"}

But the next is correct:

```
rules1 =  {"A" -> "BC", "B" -> "AC", "C" -> "AB"};
rules2 =  {"AA" -> "A", "BB" -> "B", "CC" -> "C"};
NestList[StringReplace[StringReplace[#, rules1], rules2]&, "A", 4]
```

Out = {"A", "BC", "ACAB", "BCABCAC", "ACABCACABCAB"}

Is it possible to get this result with `SubstitutionSystem`?

Comment: Your `NestList` looks fine and reflects exactly what you want. I do not know if there is any point in asking whether a convenience command such as `SubstitutionSystem` was designed for this specific case. I'd rather stick to the powerful primitives of the language such as `NestList`.

Comment: @user293787, I would like to take advantage of the opportunities of this package: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/wolframphysics/Tools/guide-page

Comment: SubstitutionSystem applies the rule sequentially. Therefore, you must specify the more specific rules klike: "AA" -> "A" before the simpler rules like:  "A" -> "BC"

Comment: @DanielHuber, unfortunately any permutations of rules give the same result

Comment: MMA version 13.1  I get different results from: rules1 = {"A" -> "BC", "B" -> "AC", "C" -> "AB", "AA" -> "A",   "BB" -> "B", "CC" -> "C"}; and 
rules2 = {"AA" -> "A", "BB" -> "B", "CC" -> "C", "A" -> "BC", 
   "B" -> "AC", "C" -> "AB"};